# Настройка google charts через метод setOption класса EmbeddedChartBuilder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Вставляю диаграмму в виде таблицы в лист, используя EmbeddedChartBuilder.

```
function TableTest() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.TABLE)  
  .addRange(spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B11'))
  .setOption('showRowNumber', true)
 // .setOption('width','80')
  .setPosition(3, 4, 0, 0)  
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);  
  };
```

1. Где найти список опций для setOptions. Google предлагает смотреть здесь https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table ,но, например, опции width и height в этом описании, должны быть string и возможно подставлять значения, как '100px', '80em' или '60'. Но код работает, только, если значение без кавычек, то есть число (с кавычками не работает):

```
.setOption('width', 80)
```

2. Почему вообще без опций width и height, таблица большего размера, чем отображаемые данные, то есть не происходит подгонки под размер данных.
3. Как сделать автоматическую подгонку таблицы под отображаемые данные.

Comment: Сколько ни боролся с этим, так и не смог найти подходящий алгоритм подбора параметров. Насколько я понимаю, часть параметров недоступна никогда, часть используется всегда, при этом некоторые из них перекрываются друг другом или другими свойствами и методами. Подход к каждому чарту индивидуален. Полная поддержка API отсутствует. Отсутствие документации сводит на нет использование `EmbeddedCharts`.

Comment: Google отсылает к заведомо нерабочей и неполной документации(

Comment: Ну, не то чтобы отсылает. А больше не указывает явно. Вот 5 лет назад это вообще было тяжело, а сейчас более-менее терпимо. Но собирать по крупицам закрытое API практически нереально. Возможно я плохо искал, но пару собак точно на этом съел. С вероятностью в `.85`, что ваш параметр не применим =(

Comment: А вообще есть какая-либо возможность сохранить часть таблицы в виде картинки png, например?

Comment: Можно напечатать.

Comment: поясните, напечатать куда и как. Мне нужна часть range таблицы в  виде картинки, чтобы отправить в мессенджер.